# RewriteRule was matching before migration, but now browser gets a 404 error

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I have this URL rewrite rule in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^home$ home.php
```

but when I try to reach awatag.com/home I get a 404 error.

This rule worked perfectly before moving the domain to GoDaddy.

Comment: In this very case you could get away with enabling `Options All +MultiViews` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Check your old apache config against your new apache config.  It might be something as simple as not having mod_rewrite configured on your new server.

Answer (score 0):

Try prefixing the redirect path with a leading slash:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^home$ /home.php [L]
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^home$ /home.php doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
RewriteBase /
```

seems to help some people.